# Typescript Passing prop as one of the objects's keys - values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, parameter-passing

I am using react native and trying to pass one of string values to another component.

The `type` object looks like this:

```
export const ScannerAction = {
  move: 'move',
  inventory: 'inventory',
  demand: 'demand',
  supply: 'supply'
};
```

so when I pass a value called `operationType` I want it to be one of the strings: `move`, `inventory`, `demand` or `supply`.

the child component would have an interface like this:

```
interface IIProps {
  id: string;
  otherStuff: any;
  operationType: should be the type of ScannerAction
}
```

I could use

```
operationType: 'supply' | 'demand' | 'inventory' | 'move'
```

but I want it to be dynamic and editable only in one place. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to use an enum instead of an object:

```
enum ScannerAction {
  move = 'move',
  inventory = 'inventory',
  demand = 'demand',
  supply = 'supply'
};

interface IIProps {
  id: string;
  otherStuff: any;
  operationType: ScannerAction
}
```

If you want to stick to an object, you can use `keyof` to get the keys and then get the values:

```
const ScannerAction = {
  move: 'move',
  inventory: 'inventory',
  demand: 'demand',
  supply: 'supply'
} as const; // make this const so that ScannerActionValues becomes a union of all values instead of string

type ScannerActionValues = typeof ScannerAction[keyof typeof ScannerAction];

interface IIProps {
  id: string;
  otherStuff: any;
  operationType: ScannerActionValues;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to use enum, but couldn't use it proper;y when comparing enum value with other values in components. I was overthinking this. Everything works, thank you

Answer (score 1):

What about to use enum?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

```
export enum ScannerAction {
    move = 'move',
    inventory = 'inventory',
    demand = 'demand',
    supply = 'supply'
}
```

interface usage:

```
interface IIProps {
    id: string;
    otherStuff: any;
    operationType: ScannerAction
}
```