# How to make a generic textfield that is controllable by react-hook-forms?

Tags: reactjs, typescript-generics, react-hook-form

**Context:** I am using react-hook-forms to create a list of text fields (controlled by the controller).I'm finding that I'm writing quite a bit of similar code and thought to create a generic text field.

My problem is two fold:

1. How do I pass through the properties of my interface that populate the `name` of the textfield?
2. How do I pass through the generic object type successfully though props for use in the component leveraging react-hook-forms?

The code I have is as follows:

```
interface GenericTextfieldProps<T extends FieldValues> {
    formLabel: string;
    name: keyof T;
    control: Control<T>;
};

function GenericTextfield<T extends FieldValues>({
    formLabel,
    name,
    control,
}: GenericTextfieldProps<T>) {
    return (
        <Stack direction="column" spacing={0.5}>
            <Controller
                render={({ field }) => (
                    <TextField
                        {...field}
                        id="textfield"
                        label=""
                        size="small"
                        fullWidth
                        sx={{ ml: 3 }}
                        disabled
                        variant="outlined"
                    />
                )}
                name={name}
                control={control}
            />
        </Stack>
    );
}
```

However, when I translated my code to make it more generic (i.e parsing through a generic type),  `name={name}` started throwing the following string error:

`Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'Path<T>'.`

For Q1:

First I tried name: string in props. This did not work as react-hook-forms needs the actual key to allow the controller to do it's magic.

I determined from this [post 9 months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70739225/typescript-passing-prop-as-one-of-the-objectss-keys-values) that I could use `keyof {my typescript object}`in props. This was very successful.

However, when I translated my code to make it more generic (i.e parsing through a generic type),  `name={name}` started throwing the following string error:

`Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'Path<T>'.`

Looking more into react-hook-forms, it seems like there is some sort of relative Field path which needs the keys and values from the actual typescript object. I also think [this stackoverflow post is related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73381505/attempting-to-configure-a-generic-component-with-react-hook-form) but unfortunately there are no answers there that I can reference.

I think it has something to do with how the form finds the path with the keys and values (gleaned from the controller.d.ts file here:

```
export declare type UseControllerProps<TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues, TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>> = {
    name: TName;
    rules?: Omit<RegisterOptions<TFieldValues, TName>, 'valueAsNumber' | 'valueAsDate' | 'setValueAs' | 'disabled'>;
    shouldUnregister?: boolean;
    defaultValue?: FieldPathValue<TFieldValues, TName>;
    control?: Control<TFieldValues>;
};
```

Ideally, if anyone has done this before I would be looking for an elegant solution using react-hook-forms in a more generic manner. Note: I'm not wedded to using `keyOf` any other solutions/ideas are welcome as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were on the right track with `UseControllerProps`.

By extending your props interface with `UseControllerProps<T>` where `T` has been extended with `FieldValues`, you now have access to set the Controller props that you would like to consume.

```
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { Controller, FieldValues, UseControllerProps } from 'react-hook-form';

interface GenericTextfieldProps<T extends FieldValues>
    extends UseControllerProps<T> {
    formLabel: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
}

function GenericTextfield<T extends FieldValues>({
    name,
    control,
    formLabel,
    disabled = false,
}: GenericTextfieldProps<T>) {
    return (
        <Stack direction="column" spacing={0.5}>
            <Controller
                render={({ field }) => (
                    <TextField
                        {...field}
                        id="textfield"
                        label={formLabel}
                        size="small"
                        fullWidth
                        sx={{ ml: 3 }}
                        disabled={disabled}
                        variant="outlined"
                    />
                )}
                name={name}
                control={control}
            />
        </Stack>
    );
}
```